# Laravel with Jquery - Ajax Throwing 500 Error - Prob with Server Side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

. Hello y'all.  I am trying to gather a few variables and send it to my controller. I keep getting a 500 error and can't figure out where exactly I'm going wrong other than I'm pretty sure its server side. Any pointers about where I went wrong or better practices would be greatly appreciated! Thank yall so much!

Route:

```
/*Ajax Edit Price on Price Page*/
    Route::post('edit_price', array(
        'as'    => 'edit_price',
        'uses'  => 'PriceController@edit_price'     
    ));
```

Controller:

```
public function price_edit(){

    console.log($id_and_db);

    }
```

JS:

```
/*Ajax edit prices*/
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.edit_button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id_and_db   = $(this).prop('name').replace('edit', 'newprice'),
        new_price   = $('[name=' + id_and_db + ']').val();

        $('#test').val(id_and_db);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit_price',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "id_and_db": id_and_db,
                "new_price": new_price,
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#edit_results").html(data);
                $("#edit_results").addClass('panel callout radius');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            },
        });
    });

});
```

Error Message:

```
POST http://localhost/local/example/public/edit_price 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/local/example/public/edit_price". jquery.min.js:4
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
 price_index_admin.js:40
error price_index_admin.js:41
Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did

```
'uses'  => 'PriceController@edit_price'
```

but your controller method is `price_edit()`.

Try change your controller method to

```
public function edit_price() {
```

Comment: @gv0029 Small errors can be really painful to find isn't it? :D You're welcome!

Comment: Yeah I keep thinking I must not understand something about the actual ajax and forget that typos are just as deadly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid for a controller - it looks like you are trying to run java inside php:

```
public function price_edit(){

    console.log($id_and_db);

    }
```

it should be something like this

```
public function price_edit(){

    return Response::json(['your response here']);

    }
```

Comment: I was just trying some debugging. Still get the 500 error when I try this, but thanks though.